# Square Integrable random variables are always integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

If $X$ is any random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$, how can I show that $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$, ie that $X$ is integrable? I'm quite sure that it must be true, but cannot see a way to show it.

Comment: Jensen's implies $\mathbb{E}|X| \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to prove it.

1. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality :
   \begin{equation}
   \mathbb E|X|=\mathbb E|X\times1|\leq \mathbb E\left([X^2]\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbb E\left([1]\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\mathbb E\left([X^2]\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty
   \end{equation}
2. Jensen's inequality : which is somewhat faster by taking $f(X)=X^2$
   \begin{equation}
   \mathbb E[X^2]\geq\mathbb (E[X])^2 \implies \mathbb E|X|\leq \mathbb E\left([X^2]\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty
   \end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the inequality $2ab\leqslant a^2+b^2$ with $a=\lvert X(\omega)\rvert$ and $b=1$ in order to get for each $\omega$
$$
\lvert X(\omega)\rvert\leqslant X(\omega)^2/2+1/2.
$$
Then take the expectation.